# Concatenation of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

How can I concatenate year, month and day in order to use it in where clause of query?

I tried to do that but it bring error message, The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. SQL State: 22007

```
Select * 
from table_name 
where DocDate >= cast(YEAR({?dateto}) as varchar(4)) + '-02-' + cast(DAY({?dateto}) as varchar(2))
```

Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you do that?  Just use [`datefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
where docdate >= datefromparts(YEAR({?dateto}), 2, DAY({?dateto}))
```

Of course, February has only 28 or 29 days, so you might need to take this into account:

```
where docdate >= datefromparts(YEAR({?dateto}), 2,
                               (CASE WHEN DAY({?dateto}) > 28 THEN 28 ELSE DAY({?dateto}) END)
                              )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon